# Populate table data with $http.get on dropdown option selected in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am new to Angular and would like to learn how to accomplish this task below:

I have a dropdown that contains a list of table names from a database. When a table name is selected from the drop down I want to make an HTTP GET call to a web API method which returns the list of column names in the selected table.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Table Information</h1>
            <hr />
            <div ng-controller="TableController" class="col-lg-6">
                <label>Select a Table:</label>
                <select id="tablename" ng-options="table.Name for table in tables track by table.Name" ng-model="data.selectedOption" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>{{data.selectedOption}}</h1>
            <hr />
            <div ng-controller="TableColumnController" class="col-lg-6">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Max Characters</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="tablecolumn in tablecolumns">
                        <td>
                            {{tablecolumn.Name}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{tablecolumn.Type}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{tablecolumn.MaxCharacters}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TableColumnController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/',
    {
        params: {
            tablename: "smsn"
        }
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.tablecolumns = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error!");
    });
});

app.controller('TableController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.tables = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error!");
        });
});
```

What is the best way to do this?

Here is just an example of what it looks like:

[image: Example]

UPDATED CODE:

```
          <div class="row" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Table Information</h1>
            <hr />
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label>Select a Table:</label>
                <select id="tablename"
                        ng-options="table.Name for table in tables track by table.Name"
                        ng-model="data.selectedOption"
                        ng-change="getColumns(data.selectedOption)"
                        class="form-control"></select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>{{data.selectedOption.Name}}</h1>
            <hr />
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column Name</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Max Characters</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="tablecolumn in tablecolumns">
                            <td>
                                {{tablecolumn.Name}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{tablecolumn.Type}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{tablecolumn.MaxCharacters}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.factory('tableService', ['$http', function ($http) {

                function getColumns(selection) {
                    $http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/', { params: { tablename: selection } }).success(function (data) {
                        return data;
                    });
                }

                function getTables() {
                    $http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/').success(function (data) {
                        return data;
                    });
                }

                return { getColumns: getColumns, getTables: getTables }
            }]);

        app.controller('ctrl', ['$http', '$scope', 'tableService', function ($http, $scope, tableService) {

            $scope.tables = tableService.getTables();

            $scope.getColumns = function (selection) {
                $scope.tablecolumns = tableService.getColumns(selection.Name);
            }

        }]);

    </script>
}
```

Comment: It is okay for me. But you could define services (+angula-resource) to retrieve JSON/XML data.

Comment: @felipsmartins I don't think I quite understand what you are asking. Are you wanting me to find a neutral data source for pulling in JSON data? So we can mess with the same data?

Comment: Read more about angular services and how the controller should play it's row in a view. For instance, the controller should not make the $http call, a service should.

Comment: use `ng-change` and make request inside the corresponding controller function

Comment: @FernandoPinheiro Okay, I think that's what I need to do. Is it best to use $watch on the drop down?

Comment: have a look at this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/c5vtx8RJlcyVmbWcgBp8?p=preview). Hope this helps. :)

Comment: First of all, do not use two controllers. And use a ng-change on the select to know when to load the columns of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for multiple controllers, and you'll need to bind to [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). Observe the following example, specifically, the binding to `getStuff`...

```
<select 
    id="tablename" 
    ng-options="table.Name for table in tables track by table.Name" 
    ng-model="data.selectedOption" 
    ng-change="getStuff(data.selectedOption)"
    class="form-control">
</select>
```

---

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getStuff = function(selection) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/', { 
            params: { tablename: selection }
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.tablecolumns = data;
        });
    }
}
```

I would recommend moving this logic into an injectable service, most likely your next step. Something like...

```
app.factory('TableService', ['$http', function($http) {
    function getMetaData(selection) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/', { params: { tablename: selection } }
    }

    return { getMetaData: getMetaData }
}]);
```

---

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'TableService', function ($scope, TableService) {
    $scope.getStuff = function(selection) {
        TableService.getMetaData(selection).then(function(response) {
            $scope.tablecolumns = response.data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/azcb62hrL7OAYwhvTC4U?p=preview) - simplified demo

---

Edit per your example and updated code, give this a shot...

```
app.controller('ctrl',...

    tableService.getTables().then(function(response) {
        $scope.tables = response.data;
    });

    $scope.getColumns = function (selection) {
       tableService.getColumns(selection.Name).then(function(response) {
            $scope.tablecolumns = response.data
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have updated my code match your example but I keep getting a $http is not defined. Do you see why I might be getting this error?

Comment: You're likely not injecting the $http service into your factory correctly. Can you double check your injection signature and let me know the results? Also FYI in my example I have not "min safe'd" it. Are you minifying this code?

Comment: Okay, so I was trying to call the $http.get in the controller but the function did not have $http in the parameters. Where am I wanting to call the $http.get to populate the table dropdown?

Comment: You're going to want to call it on the factory I created. See my last two snippets. We inject $http into the service, then inject the service into the controller. Does that make a bit more sense? You're actually calling the factory method, which in turn calls $http.get, returning a promise, that is resolved via the then() callback

Comment: @Aaron I have changed the signatures for minifying. Does this help you in regards to your question at all?

Comment: I have updated my code and I think it is really close I am getting the correct data from the api and it is hitting all the pieces. But when I select and option the method gets called but it is not populating the columns table. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your `ng-controller="ctrl"` is only isolate to that top `<div>`. Maybe make it cover more of your DOM?

Comment: Ya, I have tried that. I look at fiddler and the web api methods are getting called and returning data but it is like getColumns and getTables functions are not returning the data. I have updated my code. Thank you for all your help....you have already done so much.

Comment: no worries, check out my edit to see if it helps - you're still needing to resolve the promises via `then()`

Comment: That worked perfectly. I really appreciate all your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: nice :) np happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You should not use two controllers for this purpose, instead you can use a service or factory for $https request to get you data from the server.

You should also use ng-change to invoke table column name info call

Try this

in app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('userFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  var dataFactory = {};


  dataFactory.getTableNames = function() {
    /*$http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/').
           success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.tables = data;
           }).
           error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               alert("error!");
           });*/
    data = [{
      id: 1,
      tableName: 'table1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      tableName: 'table2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      tableName: 'table3'
    }];
    return data;
  }
  dataFactory.getColumnNames = function() {
    alert('implement your logic here . ');
    /*  $http.get('http://localhost:61475/api/SxTableInfo/',
        {
            params: {
                tablename: "smsn"
            }
        }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.tablecolumns = data;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("error!");
            });*/
  }
  return dataFactory;
}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'userFactory', function($scope, userFactory) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


  $scope.items = userFactory.getTableNames();
  $scope.getColumnNames= function(){
    userFactory.getColumnNames();

  }

}]);
```

in HTML,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.6"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
       <select ng-change="getColumnNames()" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.tableName as item.tableName for item in items"></select>

  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/c5vtx8RJlcyVmbWcgBp8?p=preview) for the same.